# Model not displaying data, but saving data, Laravel

Tags: laravel

I have an `Image` model it saves data through the controller but it doesn't display data, please what's the issue.

The Model

```
namespace App;
use App\Event\NotifyPhoto;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class Image extends Model
{
public $table = "images";
protected $guarded = [];
public $timestamps = false;
public function property_user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\PropertyUser');
}
public function facility(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Facility');
}

}
```

The Image controller

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Http\Requests\ImageRequest;
use App\Property;
use App\PropertyUser;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Facility;
use App\Image;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL;
use Illuminate\Support\Carbon;

class ImageController extends Controller
{
    public function create()
    {
    dd(Image::all());//This comes back empty

    return view('settings.photos');

    }

    public function store(Request $request)
{ 
        $property_users = PropertyUser::where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()-    >id)->get();
        foreach ($property_users as $property_user) {
            $id = $property_user->property_id;
        }

        $rules = [
            'file' => 'required',
            'description' => 'required',
            'tag' => 'required'
        ];

        $request->file('file');
        if (!empty($request->file('file'))) {
            $file_count = count($request->file('file'));
        } else $file_count = null;
        foreach (range(0, $file_count) as $index) {
            $rules['file.' . $index] = 'image|mimes:jpeg,gif,webp,bmp,png|max:2048';
        }

        $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return back()
                ->withErrors($validator)
                ->withInput();
        } else {
            $files = $request->file('file');
            $description = $request->input('description');
            $tag = $request->input('tag');

            $i = 0;
            foreach ($files as $file) {
                $i++;
                $file1 = $file->move(public_path() . '/upload_images/', $file->getClientOriginalName());
                $url1 = $url = URL::to("/") . '/upload_images/' . $file->getClientOriginalName();
                $image = Image::create([
                    'filename' => $url,
                    'description' => $description,
                    'facility_id' => 16, //$new_fac->id ?? $f->id,
                    'created_at' => Carbon::now(),
                    'updated_at' => Carbon::now(),
                    'tag' => $tag
                ]);
                dd($image);//This displays the files saved and their ids in     the table

               ]
            }
            return redirect('settings/photos');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't display data"? Could you post a code sample of when that's happening?

Comment: Make sure the table is not empty?

Comment: it just returns an empty collection? Can you show what it returns exactly? Have you made sure your table is called images and that it's not empty?

Comment: The images table is not empty, but when i try to read from it , it comes back with an empty array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding this to your `App/Image`:

```
protected $fillable = [
    'filename',
    'description',
    'facility_id',
    'created_at',
    'updated_at',
    'tag',
];
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#mass-assignment

Also, can you confirm a new row is being added to the database?

Comment: There's `protected $guarded = [];` which (although a terrible idea) would achieve the same result.

Comment: @HH one more thing i have done as you said but the images aren't showing based on my controller, but when i dd it shows the images

Comment: This is my new model<?php

namespace App;

use App\Event\NotifyPhoto;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Image extends Model
{
    public $table = "images";
    protected $guarded = [];
    public $timestamps = false;protected $fillable = [
    'filename',
    'description',
    'facility_id',
    'created_at',
    'updated_at',
    'tag',
];

    public function property_user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\PropertyUser');

    }

    
}